# vue compile shared computed functions into separate package

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

How can i share common `vue/nuxt` specific code between different packages?

I do not want to use a `monorepo` however I have shared code that I want to separate into its own package. The shared code(new package), is written using `@nuxtjs/composition-api` and is just shared `computed` and `methods` used over and over in different components/templates.

I do not want the package to be setup as a plugin. Instead something to directly import to utilize tree shaking(just like the `composition-api`).

I am familiar with `rollupjs` to create the importable modules.

```
//New package
//index.js
export { default as isTrue } from './src/isTrue'
...

//src/isTrue
import { computed } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export default (p) => {
  return computed(() => p === 'true') //Im not 100% is this will break reactivity?!?!
}
```

I havent had any issues compiling this into `.ssr, .esm, .min` formats via `rollupjs`

The issue I come across is when i import the new package into a working file.

```
import { isTrue } from 'new-package'

export default{
name: 'testComp',
setup(props){
  return {
    isActive: isTrue(props.active)
  }
}
```

will yield:

```
[vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) before using any function.
```

i understand the `@nuxtjs/composition-api` is a wrapper of the VueCompositionAPI.

i dont really want to install the new package as a plugin therefore I have omitted the install on the new package(install ex: https://github.com/wuruoyun/vue-component-lib-starter/blob/master/src/install.js)

Comment: Instead of using the `composition-api` i could use the `options api` under `computed:{}` and remove `composition-api` on the new package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the `options API`

```
//library.js
export default function(){ // access to this -> arrow function doesnt have this
   return this.disabled == true // when applied using the options api this will be the vue context aka property disabled
}
```

library.js is compiled using `rollupjs` and can be imported

```
//component.vue
import { isDisabled } from 'library'

export default {
  //Composition API:
  setup(props){
   return {
    //stuff
   }
  },
  //Options API:
  computed:{
    isDisabled,
  }
}
```